# AWS Jclouds resource not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins, jclouds

When I try to provision an executor via JClouds in Jenkins I get the following error:

*javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jclouds.rest.ResourceNotFoundException: **The security group 'sg-4a6bb62f' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-14a06d71**'*

```
> 'vpc-14a06d71' <- isnt my default VPC.
> 
> vpc-e68bxxxx <- that is my default VPC.
```

Why is AWS or JClouds giving this erroneous error?!

Btw, I have verified that the security group is valid.

Comment: Is it possible to see the HTTP request in JClouds?